# How to fill a 2D array in C according to their values?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

EDIT: in the print_tables function, i have the for-loop that fills all the values accordingly. What wrong with it is that i'm trying to calculate the values for each element, however there getting filled with the wrong input. The vars elasticity and numOfDimples are correct, however for the var distance and its calculation is wrong. For the calculation

```
            dimpleFactor = 120 - numOfDimples;
            distance = elasticity * (800 - (dimpleFactor * dimpleFactor));
```

it's multiplying the end result of elasticity rather than multiply it accordingly. for example:

let's say elasticity = 0.14 and numOfDimples = 102.
so when the for-loop gets executed for the first time around what happens is
elasticity = 1.12 (the last value of elasticity), so this will pretty much ruin the equation.

Here's the code in full, any suggestions to fixing it will really be appreciated. Like if i should use a struct or union (as im really new to C).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

const float MIN = 0.0;
const float MAX_ELAS = 1.0;
const float MAX_DIFFERENCE = 10.0;


void get_data(float *minDimples, float *maxDimples, float *elasticity);
void print_tables(float minDimples, float maxDimples, float elasticity);

void get_data(float *minDimples, float *maxDimples, float *elasticity)
{
    float minMaxDifference;
    bool minBool, maxBool, elasBool = false;
    minBool = maxBool = elasBool; //set booleans to false

    /* Prompt the user for data using a do-while loop
    * Exit the loop when data is valid
    */
    do {
        /* Get MINIMUM number of dimples data */
        printf("Enter the minimum number of dimples:\n");
        scanf("%f", minDimples);
        /* Check if it's valid */
        if (*minDimples < MIN) {
            //invalid data entered
            minBool = false;
        }
        else {
            minBool = true;
        }

        /* Get MAXIMUM number of dimples data */
        printf("Enter the maximum number of dimples:\n");
        scanf("%f", maxDimples);
        /* Check if it's valid */
        if (*maxDimples < MIN || *maxDimples < *minDimples) {
            maxBool = false;
        }
        else {
            maxBool = true;
        }

        minMaxDifference = *maxDimples - *minDimples;
        if (minMaxDifference > 10) {
            minBool = false;
        }

        /* Get elasticity step size data */
        printf("Enter the elasticity step size:\n");
        scanf("%f", elasticity);
        /* Check if it's valid */
        if (*elasticity < MIN || *elasticity > MAX_ELAS) {
            elasBool = false;
        }
        else {
            elasBool = true;
        }


        /* Print error message if something is invalid */
        if (elasBool == false || minBool == false || maxBool == false) {
            printf("Sorry, but your data is invalid\n");

        }
        else {
            /* Do nothing */
            printf("");
        }

    } while (elasBool == false || minBool == false || maxBool == false);


}


void print_tables(float minDimples, float maxDimples, float elasticity)
{
    float elasticityLength, minMaxDifference, setElasticity, dimpleFactor, distance, numOfDimples;
    float table[10][10]; //elasticity step size's and distance's (rows cannot be longer than 10 & columns cannot be > 100)
    int  rows, columns, i, j;

    setElasticity = elasticity;
    numOfDimples = minDimples;


    elasticityLength = MAX_ELAS / elasticity; //How many times does elasticity step size go into 1? /Columns
    minMaxDifference = maxDimples - minDimples; //How many times should rows go along? /Rows


    /* This loop is for filling the table 2D array */
    for (rows = 0; rows <= minMaxDifference; rows++) {
        elasticity = setElasticity;
        for (columns = 0; columns < elasticityLength; columns++) {

            /* Setting the dimple size's. table[0][i] */
            if (columns == 0 && rows >= 1) {
                printf("%.0f\t", numOfDimples);
                table[columns][rows] = numOfDimples;
                if (numOfDimples <= maxDimples) {
                    numOfDimples++;
                }
            }

            if (rows != 0 && columns != 0) {
                dimpleFactor = 120 - numOfDimples;
                distance = elasticity * (800 - (dimpleFactor * dimpleFactor));
//  <<< THIS calculation is wrong
                printf("%.1f\t", distance);
                table[columns][rows] = distance;
            }

            /* Setting the elasticity along column 1. table[i][0] */
            if (rows == 0 && columns >= 1) {
                printf("%.02f\n", elasticity);
                table[columns][rows] = elasticity;
                elasticity += setElasticity;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n-------------------\n");
    /* Print the table */
    for (i = 0; i <= minMaxDifference; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < elasticityLength; j++) {
            printf("%0.2f\t", table[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    float minDimples, maxDimples, elasticity;


    get_data(&minDimples, &maxDimples, &elasticity);
    print_tables(minDimples, maxDimples, elasticity);

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried putting outside the column loop and still had no luck. I want it to look sort of like 
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/powerpoint/powerpoint_p3s21.html 
(with distance having the correct values).

Any suggestions or solutions will be greatly appreciated! Also is using a 2D array appropriate for this?

Comment: I suggest renaming `columns` and `rows` to `column` and `row`, now it looks like they are the total number instead of the current index.

Comment: Why are `elasticityLength`, `minDimples`, `maxDimples`, and `minMaxDifference` floating point numbers when you use them with the integer indices of the array?

Comment: @Arkku yeah im aware of that, not really interested in that at the moment though. just want a working table. ty though

Comment: @user2878551 Yet you've hard-coded the array to 10×10, and there is no check that the calculations for `elasticityLength` and and `minMaxDifference` do not exceed that.

Comment: How about "distance = table[columns][0] * ......" ?

Comment: @arkku in my other method i do lol. sorry :(

Comment: @racraman wont that only fill the top row? which the top row is reserved for minMaxDifference

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks heaps for your input! really helps

Comment: @user2878551  When you want to add one by one why don't add like this - `table[columns][rows] +=setElasticity`.

Comment: @ameyCU because setElasticity != 1 ?

Comment: The top row (ie. rows == 0) holds your calculated elasticity.  Since "rows" is the outer loop, that column (ie. table[columns][0] ) gets, as you say, "calculated all at once" first.  Your distance calculation can therefore use those values since they're performed when "rows" > 0.   EDIT: Sorry, got that wrong, and you're right.   Apologies.

Comment: @user2878551  `setElasticity` is already initialized to `elasticity`. Then why you need `setElasticity` ?

Comment: @racraman nah that's okay. thanks though. the distance calculation is really just an else statement for the column loop. just i dont want it to fill table[0][0] :)

Comment: @ameyCU if i dont have setElasticity and just have elasticity. Then i would have to do elasticity += elasticity. and that would double it each time, rather than plus it by the set value. eg: (elasticity += elasticity)
1 += 1; equals 2. 2+= 2; equals 4. 4 += 4; equals 8. now if i use setElasticity instead.
1 += 1; equals 2. 2+= 1; equals 3. etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the code structure, given that the entire 2D array is only local to `print_tables` and the only purpose is to print the array, you might just as well remove the array altogether and print the values directly instead of storing them temporarily only to re-iterate over the array printing them.

I'd also handle the “header” row and column separately from the data rows; this simplifies the code by removing the `if`s, so it's easier to track what's going on. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const static float MAX_ELAS = 1.0;

void print_tables(unsigned minDimples, unsigned maxDimples, float minElasticity) {
    const unsigned elasticityLength = (unsigned) ceilf(MAX_ELAS / minElasticity);
    float elasticity = minElasticity;

    // Header row
    (void) printf(" "); // Empty (0,0) cell
    for (unsigned col = 0; col < elasticityLength; ++col) {
        (void) printf("\t%.02f", elasticity);
        elasticity += minElasticity;
    }

    for (unsigned dimples = minDimples; dimples <= maxDimples; ++dimples) {
        float dimpleMultiplier = 120.0f - dimples;
        dimpleMultiplier = 800.0f - (dimpleMultiplier * dimpleMultiplier);
        elasticity = minElasticity;

        (void) printf("\n%u", dimples); // Header column
        for (unsigned col = 0; col < elasticityLength; ++col) {
            float distance = elasticity * dimpleMultiplier;
            (void) printf("\t%.1f", distance);
            elasticity += minElasticity;
        }
    }
    (void) printf("\n"); // Terminate last row
}

int main (void) {
    // TODO: Read input instead of hard-coded values (or use command-line?)
    print_tables(121, 125, 0.14);
    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
         0.14    0.28    0.42    0.56    0.70    0.84    0.98    1.12
121     111.9   223.7   335.6   447.4   559.3   671.2   783.0   894.9
122     111.4   222.9   334.3   445.8   557.2   668.6   780.1   891.5
123     110.7   221.5   332.2   443.0   553.7   664.4   775.2   885.9
124     109.8   219.5   329.3   439.0   548.8   658.6   768.3   878.1
125     108.5   217.0   325.5   434.0   542.5   651.0   759.5   868.0
```

As a suggestion for further cleaning up, perhaps specify `elasticityStep` which is the increment of `elasticity` between columns, and separate `minElasticity`, `maxElasticity` instead of `elasticityLength`. Then the column loops would be like:

```
for (elasticity = minElasticity; elasticity <= maxElasticity; elasticity += step)
```

Comment: @Arrku ive added the whole code in. With a lot better description. thank a lot for the reply though :D

Comment: @user2878551 Did you try the change I suggested? If this is not what you were looking for, how about you give one manually calculated row of desired values for `elasticity`.

Comment: @Arrku of course i tried what you suggested. however it did not work :'( how do i manually do it? do you mean do it without a for-loop?

Comment: @user2878551 I mean give the input values as numbers and use, e.g., a calculator (or pencil and paper =) to produce one row of correct results, as it is still unclear what the code should be doing.

Comment: @arrku Did you look at it again? thought it would be clearer :(. I want the user to enter the values. so it can just be changed to the users desire.

Comment: @user2878551 Yes, I understand that, but what I don't understand is what the _correct_ output should be. For instance, if `elasticity = 0.14` and `minDimples = 0` and `maxDimples = 5`, then what should the output be for, say, row 1? If this is a known formula you're trying to implement, you can also link to it, but I don't recognise what this algorithm is calculating (i.e., I don't know what `elasticity` _is_, much less how much it should change per column and/or per row).

Comment: @arrku okay well if i remove the array and just use printf(""). how will i use printf() to add in the minMaxDifference for example? say if i want to print 100 to 105 the first time, then print out 100 to 109 the next?

Comment: @arrku the correct output should just be. using your example elasticity = 0.14. for the first time the loop get executed table[1][0] = 0.14. table[2][0] = 0.28. then for distance. table[1][1] =
distance = 0.14 * (800 - (dimpleFactor * dimpleFactor)); HOWEVER, what is happening is: 
distance = 1.12 * (800 - (dimpleFactor * dimpleFactor)); the last value of elasticity.

Comment: @arrku all good. i ended up solving it :) all i was doing wrong was multiplying it incorrectly. what i changed was,

dimpleFactor = 120 - table[0][rows];
distance = table[columns][0] * (800 - (dimpleFactor * dimpleFactor));

thanks for helping me though!

Comment: @SpeedyMike FWIW, if that (alone) solved it, it would also have been solved by the very first change that I suggested (when applied correctly). =) Anyhow, I suggest taking a look at the version in my current answer if you're interested in ideas on how to improve the code.

Comment: Yeah nice. ty for your help. Ended up not even using a 2D array and just printing out the values